# string "System.Byte[]" at the end of a string when converting string to bytearray and back

Tags: c#, string, arrays

Im using the following methods to convert a byte array to string and vice versa in C#:

```
public static byte[] StringToByteArray(string str)
{
    byte[] b1 = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(str);
    return b1;
}

public static string ByteArrayToString(byte[] bytes)
{
    String myString = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(bytes);
    return myString;
}
```

When i read the text from a selection in a Word document into the byte array and convert it back to string, there  is a string at the end of the actual string: `System.Byte[]`. There seems to be some kind of empty string or special character at the end of the selection. This is only the case if the end of the selection is a line break. When i look at it in notepad++ (show special characters) there seems to be nothing.

Between the conversion from string to byte array and back i save the bytearray in `SQL Compact` edition database as 
DataType `"image"` (automatically created from Telerik Open Access for type `Byte[]`)

Any ideas?

Comment: Those methods look fine.  Can you show the code that calls those methods?  If you are seeing the literal string "System.Byte[]" that usually means that the ToString() method was called on a byte array.

Comment: I've checked the calls, but none of them calls the .toString() method . here is the code :  `this.value = NativeMethods.ByteArrayToString( contentItemAttribute.value);` where this.value is a string. I'm using the value in a ViewModel for a WPF TextBox that is bound to the value. maybe the toString()-method is called somewhere in between?

Comment: @user2579544 the call may be implicit - via "adding" to another string or anything that takes a string as a parameter.

Comment: It was a bug in my code. I accidently added a byte array to the string which was shown as System.Byte[] in the string in my view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a bug in my code. I accidently added a byte array to the string which was shown as System.Byte[] in the string in my view.

Comment: Exactly. The C# Language Specification has an overload `string operator +(string a, object b)` which works by concatenating the string `a` (or `""` if `a` is null) with `b.ToString()` (or `""` in case `b` is null or if `b.ToString()` returns null).